# CRM products: SAP Hybris (C4C), Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, crm, sap-commerce-cloud, sap-marketing-cloud

I would like to **compare different CRM products** [SAP Hybris (C4C) vs. Salesforce] in my work. I've not yet started because currently I have a very basic problem in understanding the difference between SAP Hybris and SAP Hybris C4C (Cloud for Customer).

SAP Hybris is divided into Commerce, Marketing, Revenue, Sales, Service. Unfortunately, I do not quite understand what is exactly summarized under SAP Hybris C4C. Has anyone a exact definition?

Furthermore, I am not sure what is better comparable:

- Salesforce Vs. SAP Hybris or
- Salesforce Vs. SAP Hybris C4C

I appreciate every hint.

Answer (score 0):

Before SAP buying hybris, hybris is an ecommerce solution. When SAP buying it, change name as SAP hybris. SAP try to use hybris word as brand. They started to move their some old/new products to hybris brand. There is no product like SAP hybris anymore. We are using SAP hybris ecommerce as name but, in community hybris is meaning of ecommerce solution.

SAP hybris C4C very different program then hybris commerce. It is SAS CRM solution and you can make customization using C# with special SDK.

Salesforce is another product but it is not a CRM solution.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the difference between SAP Hybris (Commerce, Marketing, Revenue, Sales, Service) and SAP Hybris C4C (Cloud for Customer)?**

SAP Hybris C4C is basically (SAP Hybris Sales + SAP Hybris Services) which is CRM solution.
 as of SAP Hybris Marketing and SAP Hybris Commerce they are separate solutions.

The reason for Separating Hybris C4C into Hybris Sales and Hybris Commerce is that you can configure Hybris C4C to only use either sales/services or both at the same time.